# Hide Notification bar

Tags: android

Anyone know how to disable/hide notification bar at the top which show battery and other things in android.
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Please also add how can I hide ActionBar+NotificationBar for later android versions.

Comment: Are you sure your users want you to?

Comment: @Martin: I would even pay for this.

Comment: The first two answers, hide ActionBar too. If you intend to only hide notification bar, see my answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could use a theme in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

or change parent of your AppTheme to @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</style>
```

then apply this theme on activities which you want Fullscreen like

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

or use the following code snippet:

```
public class FullScreen
    extends android.app.Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: The java code does not hide the notification bar for me.  The theme, however, worked great.

Comment: Thanks Martin, for both approaches.

Comment: You don't need to request FEATURE_NO_TITLE. Setting the fullscreen flags is enough for hiding the notification bar. Thus you can still use the action bar AND hide the notification bar.

Comment: If you do not intend to hide ActionBar too, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19902500/1576010

Answer (score 32):

The answers above hide ActionBar too.
If you intend to **only** hide notification bar, use this code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

be careful to put it before setContentView().

Comment: This is the best way i ever find. :)

Answer (score 21):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another Simple option is to add `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` on the theme you will apply to activities that don't need a notification bar...

like so..

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Works like charm

Comment: worked for me. better than add deprecated flags

Answer (score 2):

Successfully implemented a slightly modified version of @Martin's suggestion along with a custom theme to get rid of BOTH the Status and Navigation Bar.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //* Hides Notification Bar
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}
```

Top part is used to get rid of the Status bar. Add the following code to your @styles as a resource to kill off the NavBar as well.

```
 <resources> <style name="NoNav" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style> </resources>
```

After you add this to your resource file, pop open AndroidManifest.xml and chance your application theme to "@style/NoNav".

Android UI bloatware eliminated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for 4.1 or upper versions.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();    
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: It hides the status bar but I can still see the color primary dark.

Comment: @SrikarReddy try to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` at your xml layout file you are inflating into your activity. For me it helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this in onCreate() method  :

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for android developers who like minimalist and simplified one-liner code. If you intend to **only** hide notification bar, use this code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

be careful to put it before setContentView() in your on create() function of required activity.class