# Hide notification bar without using fullscreen

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-notification-bar

Here is my problem: is it possible to hide the android notification bar without using the `fullscreen` flag? I need to `adjustResize` my app when the soft keyboard is shown, but `fullscreen` apps ignore the resizing (as far as i know).

Has anyone an idea on how to make my app look fullscreen without this flag?

Here is the problem with the fullscreen flag: it only tries to show everything important, but i need to resize my app:

[image]

[image]

and the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="EditText1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="EditText2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Summary: i expected to see both `EditTexts` after my app resized and the new dimensions are redrawn

Comment: I think you only can do it with fullscreen flag like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar

Comment: hmmm. so it will end up in a lot of ugly workarounds, to resize my app on keyboard appearance. too bad :( but thx anyway

Comment: what `adjustResize` value are you using?

Comment: stateHidden|adjustResize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known and not fixed Android bug, try out the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952394/653362)

All credit to LEO

Comment: thx for searching. Unfortunately the "toggleing" is no acceptable solution in my usecase

Comment: Why not? This is an OS bug, you will not find pretty answers.

Comment: i know, that there (maybe) won't be an "perfect solution. But the toggeling shows and hides the statusbar, which is unfortunately an unacceptable effect for my customer. Ofc this is the best solution (and the fastest) so far, so I think you will be my bounty winner. (except someone else will post a better solution)

Comment: It's a shame, you might want to argue the hiding of the notification bar, leaving it may be the better option. Leaving the notification bar visible is very common.

Comment: Yeah I think so too. the only problem is, that the current version has the notification bar visible and a lot of user requested to hide it. So i hoped to find a solution to make my customer and the users happy. But i guess they have to live with it the way it is.

Comment: They'd be complaining more with scrolling or flashing notification bars ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can help:

```
getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN );
getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS );
```

You can add this to the beginning of your `onCreate()`.

Additional comments can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952394/1065190

Comment: thx. Unfortunately the "toggleing" is no acceptable solution in my usecase

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate why?

Comment: i know, that there (maybe) won't be an "perfect solution. But the toggeling shows and hides the statusbar, which is unfortunately an unacceptable effect for my customer.

Comment: But you can use toggling only once, in the beginning.

Comment: first: i misread your answer and thought it was a copy of guykuns. But after trying your code i saw, that adding the code in `onCreate()` made my app didn't resize at all (but it isn't scrolling to my bottom `EditText` anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think fullscreen also support resize,

you can do it like this in your Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `NoTitleBar` != `Fullscreen`. I need to hide the notification bar and `NoTitleBar` won't do that.

Comment: @Sprigg, how did you make your activity fullscreen?

Comment: Sorry, fix my answer
I still confirm it.
fullscreen can resize.

Comment: unfortunately it just aligns the app. Look in my original post for some screenshots and the xml

Comment: @Landry: At the moment i didn't make it fullscreen at all because i couldn't solve the problem and that is definitely a show stopper in my scenario. But i tried doing it by using a `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ` in the manifest