# Prevent a hidden status bar from reappearing after screen lock

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar, screen-lock

i want to hide status bar in my application to make it fullscreen, so i use this example [Hide Notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar) - it works fine. But if i lock the screen and then unlock it, the status bar appears, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the Android operating system status bar at the top of the screen? The one containing the battery life, time, Wifi signal, etc?

Comment: Are you adding that theme attribute in activity tag? may be you should try in application tag, if u didnt  that..

Comment: yea i've tried, it doesn't work

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the Android Status Bar and the Application Title bar, add the following to the Manifest file:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.vogella.android.temperature"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Convert"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

</manifest>
```

**UPDATED**

Also try to put this code in your relevant activity after returning from the lockscreen:

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've already done that - it works only til i lock and unlock screen

Comment: Updated my answer, you might have more luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

If security is not an issue, you can disable the lock screen while your app is running. Add the following line to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

In your activity, you can do as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private KeyguardLock lock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Disable lock screen.
        KeyguardManager keyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock = keyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("MyActivity");
        lock.disableKeyguard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Reenable the lock screen again.
        lock.reenableKeyguard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only add this to the styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in `onCreate()` before `setContentView()`

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score -2):

Write this code in your aapplication's mainfest.xml file in application tag as below:

```
<application  android:name="application package"
            android:label="application name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```