# Hide/Override notification on android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm wondering if i could intercept the notification ID for the incoming call through a broadcastreceiver then cancel the call notification or just clear all the notification on the notification's bar.

I tried to use cancelAll() but i think it works only for the notification i create.

Comment: I sure hope that isn't possible

Comment: I think that this would be useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Find a solution to walk-through this problem. i take a instant screenshot and show it.
Thanks to Radu Motisan for his tutorial. the solution use JNI instead of other way using external Library.

Here is the link : http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473