# How to disable Notification Bar?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I would like to  Disable Notification Bar using the [en](http://android-expert.blogspot.fr/2012/07/preventing-status-bar-expansion-disable.html), but when i tried to put this code in my OnCreat method in the main Activity, i have some problem. I don't know what to put in  `<height of the status bar>`, what is `params` i tried to put `handleParams`, i have the some problem and a problem using 
    `context.getWindow().addView(view, params)`; is unkown and i can't  use `context.getWindow()`

```
 View disableStatusBar = new View(context);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams handleParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        <height of the status bar>,
        // This allows the view to be displayed over the status bar
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        // this is to keep button presses going to the background window
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
        // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
        // Draws over status bar
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    context.getWindow().addView(view, params);
```

Comment: Here, give it a look.
[Answer][1]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```