# How to Override notificationbar Android

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I want to design app in which i will be launching other app like(system default calculator) . i dont want to show notification bar for calculator app. Any Solution ?

I am launching apps through my app (home app) now I want to disable the notification bar or override it for all the apps I have launched through my app is there any way ?

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4223286/2345913)

Comment: That works for only my app but I want to launch new app like I said Calculator There I dont want that bar.

Comment: I'm afraid that there should be any reason to do that kind of thing on Android.