# Alternative way for overriding home button

Tags: android

I have developed the app which is using by patients. Hospital management provide the device with app to every patient in hospital. So management asks me to run only this app in device (our devices have the version above android 3.0).I made the app which is run after booting is completed. I disabled back button. But i can't override home button. I know there is no way to override home button. But i must do it. My need is that user should not come out from the app. Give some other alternative ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make the app a launcher app, that way they will not be able to exit the app when the home button is pressed

add this to your activity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Comment: I have one doubt @tyczj

Comment: how to override notification panel?

Comment: what do you mean override it? If you mean hide it look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar

Comment: I am asking about the panel which is displayed right side corner in tablet. it includes date settings, wifi settings. Because user may uninstall app via this way. So i want to hide or do something

Comment: try what is in that link i provided. I am not sure if there is a way to or not, might be better off asking another question and see the responses